# Objective-C - default value on initialization

Tags: objective-c

I was checking some code and I found this call:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"database_v2"]) {
    //Some code here
}
```

but I couldn't find any initialization for this key in the code. 
My question is: Does the compiler set automatically any value for calls like that? Or the app will just retrieve any garbage?

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/boolForKey%3a), the method returns `NO` when the key is not found.

Comment: I know, I couldn't accept by the time I asked. I have been using here for a while, I know the rules